# I am trying to use AllArgsConstructor in my Spring boot application but it is not giving default constructor with all fields?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

I have below code but when I am trying to use it in ApplicationRunner, it gives undefined.(in hint: please create constructor with fields). i have lombok jar in my pom.xml already.

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
class Customer {

    //  public Customer(Object object, String string, String string2, HashSet hashSet) {
    //      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    //  }
    //  
    //  public Customer() { 
    //  }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String first;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String last;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_fk")
    private Set < Order > orders = new HashSet < > ();
}
```

**When using in ApplicationRunner interface's run method=>**

```java
@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

    try {
        tt.execute(status - > {
            Stream.of("Dave,Syer; Phil,Fisher; Mark,Web".split(";"))
            .map(name - > name.split(","))
            .forEach(tpl - > this.em.persist(new Customer(null, tpl[0], tpl[1], new HashSet < > ())));

            TypedQuery < Customer > customers = this.em.createQuery("select c from Customer c", Customer.class);

            customers.getResultList().forEach(customer - >
                logger.info("typed query results is : " + ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(customer)));

            return null;
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace as well as some explanation for your run method. E.g. what is `tt`? How are you compiling the classes? Are you sure that the code indicated by lombok is created as part of the class? Please provide the relevant portion from you `pom.xml`, so that we have a workable complete example.

Comment: void JpaApplicationWriter(EntityManager em, TransactionTemplate tt){
  this.em = em ; 
  this.tt = tt ;
 }

Comment: @hotzst actually i am using TransactionTemplate and entityManager dependency .

Comment: @hotzst I had to install the lombok project on mac too . seems like a configuration issue. Got solved by this link: https://www.journaldev.com/18124/java-project-lombok . Thanks anyways :)